# Why can't I read the results of piped sql from a fifo in bash?

Tags: mysql, bash, fifo

Why is `/tmp/sql.log` empty when I try to capture the results of the sql sent through the fifo:

```
fifo=/tmp/fifo.$$
mkfifo $fifo

tail -f $fifo | mysql -u root -N > /tmp/sql.log &
echo "SELECT IF(GET_LOCK('foo',1)=1,'Got lock', concat('Already locked by connection: ', IS_USED_LOCK('foo')));" >$fifo
# /tmp/sql.log is empty
```

But the non-fifo example writes as expected:

```
echo "SELECT IF(GET_LOCK('foo',1)=1,'Got lock', concat('Already locked by connection: ', IS_USED_LOCK('foo')));" | mysql -u root -N > /tmp/sql.log
# /tmp/sql.log has result of mysql query
```

I know that the commands are being sent through the fifo, because if I add `tee` to the tail:

```
fifo=/tmp/fifo.$$
mkfifo $fifo

tail -f $fifo | tee >(mysql -u root -N) &
echo "SELECT IF(GET_LOCK('foo',1)=1,'Got lock', concat('Already locked by connection: ', IS_USED_LOCK('foo')));" >$fifo
```

I can see the commands and the result of the sql. How can I capture the results of the sql rather than having it appear on stdout?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but still didn't work. I figured it out though. Answer was just use simple redirection and no tail.

Comment: The problem probably comes from the buffering done. Set `tail` and `mysql` not to buffer its outputs, and you will see the data you are looking for instantly. Check `--unbuffered` parameter in `mysql` and use `stdbuf` to set up the `tail`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Doh. The trick was to keep it simple; ditch the `tail` and just use redirection:</strike>

Redirection only works briefly - the fifo gets closed so only the first set of sql sent down the fifo is passed to `mysql`. As @poshi suggests, the answer is to use `mysql`'s `--unbuffered` option. The final answer is below this one (left for people falling into the same pitall as me).

```
# This only works for the first set of sql - the fifo is closed 
# so more can't be sent later
fifo=/tmp/fifo.$$
mkfifo $fifo

mysql -u root -N < $fifo > /tmp/sql.log &
echo "SELECT IF(GET_LOCK('foo',1)=1,'Got lock', concat('Already locked by connection: ', IS_USED_LOCK('foo')));" >$fifo
# /tmp/sql.log has results of sql query
```

### Working solution

Uses `tail` to keep the fifo open & `mysql`'s `--unbuffered` option to slurp data from it.

```
fifo=/tmp/fifo.$$
mkfifo $fifo

tail -f $fifo | mysql --unbuffered -u root -N > /tmp/sql.log &
echo "SELECT IF(GET_LOCK('foo',1)=1,'Got lock', concat('Already locked by connection: ', IS_USED_LOCK('foo')));" >$fifo
# sleep to prove that the fifo isn't closed for later queries
sleep 10
echo "SELECT CONNECTION_ID();" >$fifo
# /tmp/sql.log has results of both sql queries
```

Comment: Probably this answer solved your problem, but it have different semantics than the code given in the question. For a single query, they will work similarly; for more than a query, this answer won't work.

Comment: Thanks @Poshi - you're correct. The fifo is closed and I can't push anymore sql down it. I'll try a version that uses something like `stdbuf -oL tail -n +1 -f "$fifo" | mysql --unbuffered`

Comment: The final solution just needed `mysql --unbuffered` with a regular `tail` (no `stdbuf` needed). When I was first trying to get this working I'd searched `mysql`'s `man` page for all instances of things like "stdout", "file descriptor" and so on, and yet had still completely missed the unbuffered option! Thanks again :)